# .htaccess/mod_rewrite not working if user manually enters parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess files has a rule in it:

```
RewriteRule ^submit index.php?task=submit [L]
```

which redirects links on the site referencing index.php?task=submit to /submit.

However, I am posting information to this same page so that eventually the URL looks something like this:

```
index.php?task=submit&path=xyz&key=xyz.jpg&code=1234
```

Due to the nature of the posting method I have to post to index.php?task=submit.

Is there a rule that will rewrite the url if the user manually enters the extended path as the url?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the [`QSA` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa), which stands for Query String Append. It'll combine a rewritten query string with the incoming query string:

```
RewriteRule ^submit index.php?task=submit [L,QSA]
```

Which means that this...

```
/submit?path=xyz&key=xyz.jpg&code=1234
```

...will get properly rewritten to this:

```
index.php?task=submit&path=xyz&key=xyz.jpg&code=1234
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but it's not exactly correct. I want this: index.php?task=submit&path=xyz&key=xyz.jpg&code=1234 to be re-written to /submit while still being able to access the $_GET params even if the user manually is directed to the full path or manually enters the full path with params.

Comment: In that case, you might be better off doing that redirection manually in your code via a `Location:` header, rather than trying to do it in mod_rewrite, which is normally used for going the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

> Due to the nature of the posting method I have to post to index.php?task=submit.

This is not true. You *can* point a form to `/submit` without problems, if it is a POST form. If it is a GET form, you will need the [QSA] flag, but still no problem.

But from your comments, I conclude that you want the user to see "/submit" in the address bar but your script to have access to additional GET variables. This *cannot* work, it looks like you misunderstood the concept of rewrites:

You are not rewriting `index.php?task=submit` **TO** `/submit` (like in: magically show the user something else), but rewriting `/submit` **TO** `index.php?task=submit` (like in: the user requested `/submit`, this request gets internally rewritten to another request).

So, if the original request does not contain the information for path, key, code in any way, the rewritten request cannot either. But you could store them in the session, then redirect to `/submit` with PHP.

The script would be structured like this:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['path'])) {
    $_SESSION['path'] = $_GET['path'];
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/submit');
    session_write_close();
    exit;
}
if (isset($_SESSION['path'])) {
    $path = $_SESSION['path'];
    unset($_SESSION['path']);
    // do stuff with $path
}
```

If this is a reasonable solution depends on what this "submit" action does. For something like a search where you are retrieving information it might be okay, but for anything that stores information, the **[POST/REDIRECT/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)** pattern is a better approach.